# C# 5.0 ForEach invalid args error when using extension method in lambda

Tags: c#

I have encounted strange behaviour for for foreach method. When I put down this code:

```
var result = repository.Data.Where(<some_long_selector>).ToList();
result.ForEach(e =>
{
    e.x = CalcX(e);
    e.y = GetAllYs().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == e.x)
});
```

everything all Ok.

But when I try to use homebrew elvis "operator" (or actually "default value operator") like this :

```
var result = repository.Data.Where(<some_long_selector>).ToList();
result.ForEach(e =>
{
    e.x = CalcX(e);
    e.y = GetAllYs().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == e.x).Elvis(new Y("empty"));
});
```

where `Elvis` is

```
public static T Elvis<T>(this T? instance, T defaultValue)
{
    if (instance == null) return defaultValue;
    else return instance.Value;
}
```

I am getting "invalid args" error for ForEach method (i.e. some type error). Which is quite unexpected for me. I understand possible workarounds, but I just want to know how and why this happens and what is the least effort way to correct it, while keeping this (or slightly modified) Elvis extension function?

P.S. I am Java developer who need to support some legacy C# code while our team developing replacement for it. So, sorry, if I miss something obvious

Comment: Post the actual error text

Comment: Where is `e` defined, and why do you keep reassigning it's `x` and `y` properties in a loop?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it is in Russian. Will it help?

Comment: OT (maybe you already know this, but) unlike the `??` operator, your Elvis method will always execute that "new Y(...)"

Comment: @RufusL e is not all-defined. It is collected from three defferent sources

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, yes I know - in real code there goes static constant object

Comment: @ksbes yes - the type names, locations, stack traces are in English and will help. I suspected from the start that something wrong was going on with `T?` - this is only needed with `struct` types, as classes allow nulls anyway

Comment: You have `ForEach(x => ...` but never use that `x`, instead you use an `e`. Is that a typo in your post?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing - typos

Comment: I was wondering if you meant `ForEach(e =>` instead of `ForEach(x =>`. As shown, the code does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elvis also has to constrain its generic parameter to either `struct` or `class`, like so:

```cs
public static T Elvis<T>(this T? instance, T defaultValue)
    where T : class
{
  ...
}
```

or

```cs
public static T Elvis<T>(this T? instance, T defaultValue)
    where T : struct
{
  ...
}
```

This is because the language until very recently didn't have the concept of general nullability - only structs could be explicitly made nullable (as classes were nullable whether you liked it or not). A nullable struct was/is quietly wrapped in a `Nullable<T>` type by the compiler and all was good.

This meant that using the nullable operator in a generic signature required the parameter to be a struct, as it wouldn't have made sense with a class (until recently). Hence the requirement for an explicit struct constraint to use the operator.

However, now we have nullable reference types too, and it would make sense, you'd think, to allow the nullable operator generally without the constraint - but because of the old way of things, this leads to tangles in certain places, so the language team have said 'no' (see here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-11-25.md)

The upshot is, you have to have an explicit constraint to use the nullable operator in this way - and you have to choose between an extension method that works on reference types or struct types, but not both (I think...)

A further useful link: https://www.meziantou.net/csharp-8-nullable-reference-types.htm#generic-types

Answer (score 2):

Definition for Elvis is invalid. It has to look like this:

```
    public static T Elvis<T>(this T? instance, T defaultValue) where T : struct
```

Also in your example you call `Evis` instead of `Elvis`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my misspelling. As for your answer: *it doesn't work*, since Y() is a nullable type

Comment: @ksbes `Nullable<T>` (`T?`) can only be used on structs, not on classes (reference types) because those are always nullable (at least until recently). So maybe just remove that `?` ?

Comment: Yes you all were right!!! But it is still strange that error were being reporting for ForEach method. My change was ```public static T Elvis<T>(this T instance, T defaultValue)```

Comment: @ksbes I feel that Jason's answer is more complete and that you should accept his answer instead of mine (the green check mark).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what kind of object your working with by passing string empty and your implementation of Elvis method.
My advice is to try to write ForEach loop in a different way and separate your codes to step by step receiving the result while debugging like

```
ForEach (var item in result)
{
 item.x = CalcX(item);
 var yResult = GetAllYs().FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == item.Id);
 //then your faulty code to find out your problem while debugging the Elvis method
 item.y = yResult.Elvis(new Y("empty"))
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help: still same exception. Its seems that just using extension inside lambda changes lambda type. When I just put line ```var t = Extentions.Elvis("","")``` - error appears!